# dsPIC33EP DMA configuration issue

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab, dma

I am trying to buffer 8192 words of data from an IO Port to RAM using DMA hardware of dsPIC33EP512GM710. I have configured the interrupt source INT0 as the source for the DMA hardware. I am using MPLAB SIM to simulate. I am facing one major roadblock.

I am able to set only 10 LSB bits of the DMA start address register DMA0STAL. Even after running `DMA0STAL = 0x0FFFF;` , The special function register window shows that DMA0STAL is set to 0x03FF.

I have tried using the other DMA hardware - DMA 1,2 and 3 and still same thing happens with the DMAxSTAL register. I tried simulating in both MPLAB IDE and MPLAB X IDE. I also tried assigning value to DMAxSTAL in both assembly and C and still only 10 bits can be changed.

Thank you for your help.

PS:
I have not noticed this issue with any other register.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using real hardware to see if the simulator is wrong?

Comment: I have not tried to simulate it in hardware. I was actually looking for a hardware to buffer data coming in at 27 Mbytes/s. This device seemed to be capable of doing it. So I tried simulating it in software before comitting to buy the hardware.

Comment: Always a good idea but MPSIM can sometimes give incorrect results.  It's worth trying the same thing in hardware, feed some data into the DMA buffer and read it back to verify.  If you are sure your code is correct then you might find it's just the simulator that is giving incorrect results.

Comment: Yes. I will have to do that soon if i cannot figure out whatever is going on.

Comment: Have you checked that this part even has 8 kB of DMA RAM? That sounds like a lot.

Comment: Yes. This device has 49,152 bytes of RAM. Also, the whole of the RAM can be used by the DMA hardware according to the data sheet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with MPSIM. MPSIM is not fully supported for this device. Hardware simulation gives the correct results.